# How do I connect an outlet to two black and three white wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am rewiring a 3 prong outlet.  I pulled out the old one and found 3 white and 2 black wires attached.  I did not see a ground wire.  How do I rewire these to the new outlet?

Comment: I hope you tagged the wires before disconnecting them.  Is this outlet a switched outlet?

Comment: What do you mean "rewiring"? Are you adding wires or simply replacing the outlet?

Comment: Pictures would help.   

Comment: Where do the wires go when they leave the junction box? If they leave as 2 white/black pairs with one white all by itself then it **might** be that the lone white is actually the ground, though if that's the case it should be green instead of white.

Comment: Go get the old receptacle out of the trash. You're gonna need it.

Answer (score 1):

See attached image.
[image]

Good Luck.